# WIA advanced scanner options?

Tags: scanner

I have a Canon CanoScan LiDE210 (a USB flatbed scanner)

WIA is meant to be the new way to acquire images in Windows, as a replacement for TWAIN. Except when I use WIA I get this very limited, cut-down UI that doesn't present many options at all, just some Presets. The (somewhat hidden) custom settings screen only lets me adjust the DPI, output file type, and brightness/contrast. I can't see how I can get better control over the scanner and I have no way of knowing if it's going to perform any kind of processing of the image that I don't want.

Canon does offer TWAIN drivers, but on 64-bit operating systems it only offers 64-bit drivers, I cannot install 32-bit drivers - which is frustrating because Photoshop CC only supports TWAIN in 32-bit mode on 64-bit systems...

What's a scanner-guy to do? How can I get better control of the scanner via WIA?

Here's another frustration: the WIA UI only lets me scan up to 600dpi, even though the scanner has an optical resolution of 4800dpi.

Comment: Twain is not really "drivers" in the sence of direct memory addressing hardware stuff, more like a chunk of interfacing software. I managed to install for my (way older) cannon the 32bit twain, it is working with older 32bit photoshop, this is on win7 64bit , and it did complain a bit and i might have had to tweak something, but it has worked that way (when they said it would not).  What errors do you get? how long did you persist and search the web before assuming it would not install ?  Compatability settings ?   What Is the OS your trying to do this in?

Answer (score 1):

You can get 32 bit TWAIN scanner drivers to work with 32 bit PhotoShop CC (2015). Unfortunately, the Batch options crash PS if you use the 32 bit TWAIN plugin. I ended up having to keep my PhotoShop Elements 11 handy as it supports the 32 bit TWAIN plug-in (which ships with it) and allows Image Processing. You do have to locate and move the TWAIN plugin as per online instructions.